# Modal Dialog Not Supported in Edge Browser

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to use edge browser for CRM. But certain code is not supported in edge.One of them is the showModalDialog method. It is not supported in edge.Is there any alternative for this except window.open()?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. `window.open` is in fact okay if you only need it to work on the Web Client.

If you also want to make it available on Mobile/App, then you have to use `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` (for record pages) or `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource` (for, as the name implies, web resources).

Anything else (i.e. the `new MsCrm.CrmDialog` trick from another answer, which leverages internal CRM functions) might work and fit your needs perfectly, but is neither documented nor supported. Also, it will most likely break when you upgrade.

More information about Xrm.Utility on MSDN here: [Xrm.Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956(v=crm.6).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mscrm.CrmDialog

```
var crmDialog = new Mscrm.CrmDialog(Mscrm.CrmUri.create(url), window, width, height);
crmDialog.show();
```

Comment: This isn't working.It shows "Some Error Has Occurred" Message